# change style of closest class when input radio is selected - Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, input, radio-button, onchange

I have to make a real simple task but I cannot figure it out.

I have some cards that the user can select with a radio button. I want to higlight the selected card when the user click on the relative input radio.

I don't understand how can I select the closest class of the selected radio.

My HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="box-content">
        <input type="radio" name="box-input">
        <label>Label One</label>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="box">
    <div class="box-content">
        <input type="radio" name="box-input">
        <label>Some Two</label>
    </div>
</div>

And so on...

<button onclick="submit()">Submit</button>
```

If I do like this:

```
let boxes = document.querySelectAll('input');
const submit = () => {
    for (let i=0;i<boxes.length;i++) {
        boxes[i].checked? this.closest('.box').classList.add('selected'): console.log('nothing is selected')
    }
}
```

It says that `this.closest` is `undefined`, and it works only if the user click on the submit button.

What I want to do is just add a class to div `.box` when the radio input is selected, and remove it when change the state to unselected.

I'd like also to avoid the inline HTML "onclick" if possible.

Please pure javascript only

**EDIT**

With the suggestion of @somethinghere I added `onchange="change(this)"` to each input radio and I change my script in this way:

```
const change = el => {
    el.checked?el.closest('.box').classList.add('selected'):el.closest('.box').classList.remove('selected')
;
```

It works, it adds the class `selected` when I click on a input radio. But if I click on another input, then the class `selected` is not removed.

Suggestions?

Comment: `this` does not refer to what you think it refers to. As you are using an `arrow` function the function does _not_ get it's own `this`, so the `closest` to the window will return the window or null. Try `input onsubmit="submit(this)"` and `const submit = e => ... e.closest('box') ...` or something.

Comment: I see the problem, but how can I add (and remove) a class to `.box` when the input radio on change? Without waiting for the click on the submit button? This is basically my question.

Comment: Downvote? The reason??

Comment: I didn't man, why do I get the notification of hate? Its a valid question! The best approach you could take is maybe `<input type="radio" onchange="selectcorrect(this)" />`. Just update when the value changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added code to change the style of closest class when input radio is selected

```js
var radioAll = document.querySelectorAll('input');

for(var i = 0; i < radioAll.length; i++) 
{
   radioAll[i].onclick = function() 
   {
      //remove selected class from all box classs
      var boxElems = document.querySelectorAll(".box");
      [].forEach.call(boxElems, function(el) {
         el.classList.remove("selected");
      });
      if(this.checked)
      {
         this.closest('.box').classList.add('selected');
      }    
    };
}
```

```css
.selected{
background-color: coral;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
    <div class="box-content">
        <input type="radio" name="box-input">
        <label>Label One</label>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="box">
    <div class="box-content">
        <input type="radio" name="box-input">
        <label>Some Two</label>
    </div>
</div>

And so on...

<button onclick="submit()">Submit</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you change your code, in order to add/remove the class to `.box` when the input radio is selected/unselected? Without waiting for the click on submit?

Comment: @Danny_DDI have updated my coding. please check if any issues let me know.

Answer (score 0):

While you've already accepted an answer, I thought I'd add an alternative approach:

```js
// get a reference to the <button> element; here you only have the one <button>,
// so document.querySelector() will suffice (as it returns either the first
// Node that matches the supplied selector or null):
let submitButton = document.querySelector('button'),
  inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');

// here we use the same Arrow function syntax, which does not - by design - get
// its own 'this' reference:
const submit = () => {

  // since we have the <input> elements already we use that, along with the
  // NodeList.prototype.forEach() method:
  inputs.forEach(
  
    // here 'input' is a reference to the current <input> element of the
    // NodeList of <input> elements over which we're iterating.
    // we use Element.closest() to find the relevant '.box' element, and
    // use the Element.classList API to toggle the 'hasSelected'
    // class-name based on the supplied 'switch', the 'input.checked'; if
    // 'input.checked' is true the class-name is added to the '.box', if
    // 'input.checked' is false the class-name is removed (if the class-name
    // is already present, or not-present, when it's added or removed no
    // error is thrown and it presents no problem):
    (input) => input.closest('.box').classList.toggle('hasSelected', input.checked)
  )
}

// using the EventTarget.addEventListener() method, in place of the obtrusive
// 'onclick' in-line event-handling; here we bind the submit() function 
// (note the deliberate lack of parentheses) as the event-handler for the
// 'click' event:
submitButton.addEventListener('click', submit);
```

```css
*,
::before,
::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

body>div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 50vw;
  margin: 1em auto;
}

div.box {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 30px;
  grid-gap: 0 10px;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
  padding: 0.5em;
  border-radius: 1em;
}

div.box.hasSelected {
  border-color: limegreen;
}

div.box.hasSelected::after {
  display: contents;
  content: '✓';
  font-weight: bold;
  color: limegreen;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="box-content">
      <label><input type="radio" name="box-input">
      Label One</label>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="box">
    <div class="box-content">
      <label><input type="radio" name="box-input">
      Some Two</label>
    </div>
  </div>

  <button>Submit</button>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/ezqmwxdo/).

References:

- [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).
- [`Document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).
- [`Element.classList` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classlist).
- [`Element.closest()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest).
- [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).
- [`NodeList.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach).